# expression filters and object filters yield different results when null / undefined is involved

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

When used in the $match stage, these two aggregation stages return different documents:

```
  $expr: {
    $eq: ["$cheese", undefined]
  }
```

```
{
  cheese: {$eq: undefined}
}
```

The field `cheese` is not a property of any document in the collection.

In the second query, it returns all documents, which is expected behavior.

In the first query, it returns no documents.

What explains the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$expr` MongoDB will return always `false` when compare with `undefined` as is not a valid value to compare with.

But without `$expr` mongo uses MongoDB query language (like a `find` query) which will compare if the field exists.

Is that the reason because using the first query you do not receive anything (the comparsion is always false) and the second query return all documents (the field does not exist so the comparsion is always true).